# Multiple ViewControllers - should I use a singleton object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, singleton

I have a new project, kind of a board game, and I'm using a storyboard which has multiple view controllers in it - the game simply moves from one view to the next with the player making various decisions and then loops back.

I have an object which holds information about the player (along with a couple of methods) - the score etc. I obviously only need one instance of this object and as I want each View Controller to access the same instance, should it be a singleton? I've never used them before and I've read they're often over-used, so I just want to check if this is the correct way to do this from the start. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described is the Model for your application, holding the game data and core logic. Is there any reason to make this a singleton rather than passing it between your controllers?!

I would assume one controller calls the next and so can pass this information across?! We use singletons for services and the like but not for model data, it's not really the point of them in our experience.

Comment: After reading more on the subject, it does appear that Simon Lee's interpretation of what Apple see as "correct" is, well, correct! Nevertheless, I'm tempted in this case to use a singleton for my Model as there are a lot of views and it could get complex moving stuff between them all. I'll only be using one singleton...

Comment: At the end of the day you use what works for you, as you can see different people have different viewpoints but what works for you works!

Answer (score 1):

I personally have nothing against singletons, as long as you don't use too many of them in one project. While other people might recommend you use some other mediation for this project, I say go for it—this is exactly what you'd use a singleton for.

Comment: I agree.  A little bit of singleton never hurt anyone.  :)

Comment: I disagree, this is the model, singletons are really for things like services etc, in this case the model should really be passed between the controllers OR managed by a singleton service. The model itself should not be in my opinion.

Comment: I'd have to disagree with that. I think that you're trying to stick to the book too much. In this case, a singleton model object works quite well and removes a layer of complexity.

Comment: It's not about sticking to any book, I just don't think that 'model' data should be a singleton, simple as that. I see way too much code that blurs the boundaries with regards to development patterns and as a result is very poor. But each to their own! :)

Answer (score 0):

Singleton's can be be bad if you are developing a library component, a large server project, or for unit testing. But since you are doing an iphone game don't fret about it, it'll will be easier and faster just to use a singleton.

If you are worried about unit testing, since objetive-c is latebound and singletons are made with factory methods instead of constructors it's not hard to changeout the singleton for your unit test anyway.